# One long sheet vs many sheets

Tags: excel, formulas

I am planing to start a porject in excel which will eventually contain about 25 tables, each one with something like 70x30 cells and one main table that draws information from all other tables are presents results accordingly.
Since I don't know the exact number of rows and columns and I don't want to leaves spaces to make up for future needed rows/cols, I was thinking about putting each table in a separated sheet. Now my question is how will it affect the speed performance of my poject? (all the cells in the tables contain about a line long formula with calculations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't answer for Google but for Excel distributing over many sheets will not make a significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

for the white spaces i was using something similar to get data and leave empty cells, you can take this as start point

=QUERY({(sheet1!E4:E);(sheet2!Y4:Y)},"select * where Col1 is not null")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).